# Using variables from inside symfony 2 / twig blocks

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this

**base.html.twig**

```
<html>
  {% block template_scope_vars %}
  {% endblock %}
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**user.html.twig**

```
extends base...
{%block template_scope_vars %}
   {% set test= "bippo" %}
{%endblock%}

{%block content %}
   {{ test }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Error**

> Variable "test" does not exist

Ok please please don't tell me that I don't have to use blocks for this, the use case is more difficult than this simple example obviously. The idea is that `test` gets available in the `base.html.twig` as well, as well as any sub-templates of it that I might be using in future

Comment: Not going to work the way you want it to.  Blocks are pretty much independent.

Comment: @Cerad well that sucks big time. Is there something similar I could use? or some workaround?

Comment: Inject the variable as a twig global.

Comment: @Cerad that is like shooting a pigeon with a nuclear bomb. Besides, it doesn't solve basic use cases where you have to do just a tiny bit of logic. Hmm a real big shortcoming which makes this templating mechanism a lot weaker than say,  JSF from java

Comment: @Cerad looking at this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html probably I can create a new twig, where I only write `{% set test="foobar" %} {% include 'user.html.twig' %}` reading the doc, this should work. But I have to create a new file, which is stupid

Comment: @keyboardSmasher define a variable in a end user screen, that will get used in other templates. Say, in the template that draws the menu I want to know how to display the menu. I can give this info by checking the userrights on the final screen.

Comment: Included templates will see the variables from their parent template.  Variables flow down, not up.

Comment: It's hard to see why you would need to do this. If a template *requires* a variable, then PASS the variable to it when you render it.

Comment: And of course, every template has access to the global variable `app`, which would include your users' rights (roles).

Comment: ok @keyboardSmasher yes I could, technically, pass the variable each friggn time I render a page. But this is verbose, not the dry principle, and just plain bad. 
I give you an example of a very easy to understand use case: you are on page foo. In the menu you now want to highlight the menu entry foo. Now I can pass each friggn time a variable, say page_name => 'foo' or just define once a template scope variable in the foo.html.twig which sadly, doesn't work. This is an example, there is more use cases obviously. I solved btw this scenario by using blocks instead of variables...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Toskan Can you please post (and accept) your solution then, for future reference? :)

Comment: @keyboardSmasher there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the special use case I had I could use this. It is a shame though, there is no neater solution. All other solution I could come up with, would require to create a new file for each set of template scope variables. Which plain sucks

**base.html.twig**

```
<div id="menu"> //this is like a sidebar menu
                    <div class="menuitem  {% block foo %}{% endblock %}">
                    <a href="{{ path('MyBundle_my_routing_name_foo' }}">Foo</a>
                </div>
                    <div class="menuitem  {% block bar %}{% endblock %}">
                    <a href="{{ path('MyBundle_my_routing_name_bar' }}">Bar</a>
                </div>
<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then in

**foo.html.twig**

```
{% extends "MyBundle::base.html.twig" %}

{% block foo %}active{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
Some content specific for foo
{% endblock %}
```

**bar.html.twig**

```
{% extends "MyBundle::base.html.twig" %}

{% block bar%}active{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
Some content specific for bar
{% endblock %}
```

and then you set the css for the background of e.g.

CSS

```
menuitem.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**base.html.twig**

```
<div id="menu"> //this is like a sidebar menu
    <div class="menuitem{{ active == 'foo' ? ' active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ path('MyBundle_my_routing_name_foo') }}">Foo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuitem{{ active == 'bar' ? ' active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ path('MyBundle_my_routing_name_bar') }}">Bar</a>
    </div>
<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**foo.html.twig**

```
{% extends "MyBundle:Whatever:base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo", defaults={"param" = null}, name="foo")
 * @Route("/foo/{param}", name="foo_with_param")
 * @Template()
 */
public function fooAction($param)
{
    // This would really be getting data from the Model
    if ($param == 'something') {
        $content = 'Some content';
        $active = 'foo';
    } else {
        $content = 'Different content';
        $active = 'bar';
    }

    return array(
        'content'=> $content,
        'active' => $active,
    );
}
```

When rendering foo.html.twig, base.html.twig will get the variable "active".

Comment: @Toskan Which part? The annotations? At any rate, it's all in the symfony docs. I won't insult your intelligence by posting a link to them. You should probably set `active` once at the top of `base.html.twig` (In case it's not passed) E.g.: `{% set active = active|default(false) %}`, then you can shorten the other code a bit. `{{ active == 'foo' ? ' active' : '' }}`

Comment: in case you get several return statements, e.g. redirects after persisting or after failed checks, you'll end up copy pasting this return array all over the place.

Comment: @Toskan I don't think you get it. You HAVE to send data to the template. That's the whole point of MVC.

Comment: feel free to explain why you have to send this data to the template. Does this ever change when the template does not change? Does it need to be controlled? No. This is template styling, nothing else. Template styling should not be part of the controller.

Comment: @Toskan You talk about DRY, and then you say you want to create new almost identical template file for every active menu item? That is completely insane. foo.html.twig, bar.html.twig, baz.html.twig, etc. You just need one twig template for the menu and even just one controller that tells the template which menu item to highlight (among all of the other data that will be passed to it anyway).

Comment: but that is exactly what I have. foo has content for foo right? xD so i need `foo.html.twig` anyway. Haha you have one in your answer as well, don't you? I edited my answer so it becomes more obvious

Comment: @Toskan Hmmm...I don't know where my comment went. Anyway, I modified my answer as well. :) I guess we can agree to disagree.